# dbt cannot create two resources with identical database representations

Tags: dbt

I have a situation here as below:

There are two models in my dbt project

1. model-A

```
{{ config(
    materialized='ephemeral',
    alias='A_0001',
    schema=var('xxx_yyy_dataset')
) }}
```

2. model-B

```
{{ config(
    materialized='ephemeral',
    alias='B_0002',
    schema=var('xxx_yyy_dataset')
) }}
```

And these are getting materialized as incremental in same schema as `xxx_yyy_dataset.Table_DDD`

```
{{ config(
    materialized='incremental',
    alias='Table_DDD',
    schema=var('xxx_yyy_dataset')
) }}
SELECT * FROM {{ref('A_0001')}}
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM {{ref('B_0002')}}
```

This is working fine and it is ingesting records into target table.

Now I have introduced another model - model-C ind different package
model-C

```
{{ config(
    materialized='incremental',
    alias='Table_DDD',
    schema=var('xxx_yyy_dataset')
) }}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
$ dbt compile --profiles-dir=profile --target ide
Running with dbt=0.16.0
Encountered an error:
Compilation Error
  dbt found two resources with the database representation "xxx_yyy_dataset.Table_DDD".
  dbt cannot create two resources with identical database representations. To fix this,
  change the "schema" or "alias" configuration of one of these resources:
  - model.eplus_rnc_dbt_project.conrol_outcome_joined (models/controls/payment/fa-join/conrol_outcome_joined.sql)
  - model.eplus_rnc_dbt_project.dq_control_outcome_joined (models/controls/dq/dq-join/dq_control_outcome_joined.sql)
```

I have configured macro for custom macro as below :

```
{% macro generate_schema_name(custom_schema_name, node) -%}
    {%- set default_schema = target.schema -%}
    {%- if custom_schema_name is none -%}
        {{ default_schema }}
    {%- else -%}
        {{ custom_schema_name }}
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endmacro %}


{% macro generate_alias_name(custom_alias_name=none, node=none) -%}
    {%- if custom_alias_name is none -%}
        {{ node.name }}
    {%- else -%}
        {{ custom_alias_name | trim }}
    enter code here
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endmacro %}
```

Comment: Hi Manoj — in general we recommend _not_ anonymizing your table names. It can introduce extra mistakes that can mask the underlying issue! For example, here the error message does not match the sample code, which makes things harder to debug.

Answer (score 5):

dbt is doing its job here!

You have two models that share the exact same configuration — `conrol_outcome_joined` and `dq_control_outcome_joined`.

This means that they'll both try to write to the same table: `xxx_yyy_dataset.Table_DDD`.

dbt is (rightfully) throwing an error here to avoid a problem.

As the error message suggests, you should update one of your models to use a different schema or alias so that it gets represented in your BigQuery project as a separate table.

Comment: This is my requirement that the new model - C has to write (insert) records to same table.

Comment: Ah, then you are fundamentally breaking a paradigm of dbt — one model is represented by one table or view in your database.

Comment: But this is still possible by using macros and source model as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I had been struggling with the same problem here, I wanted to create a pipeline of tests that would only be written to a single incremental table and it triggers the same error message, but I am afraid it is not possible with DBT.

To resolve it, I created a main model that selects and unions the info from all the individual test models that I created (I previously created a model/table for each test to be applied) and that in the end with the post_hook I just drop the individual tables previously created, thus, I only stick to a final testing table that keeps all the information.

It is not what I really desired since it is not a dynamic implementation, because every test that is created needs to be added to the main table union and also to the drop statement in the post_hook, however if any test breaks individually it would not break all the other tests, neither a bunch of tables exists in my database when I start my work, you just need to orchestrate it at the right time for you.

(Another possible approach could be creating 1 model, where in the pre_hook, you create all the tables that you want, since dbt cannot make models write to the same table, in the "main" part of the model, you select and union the info of all the pre-hook tables, and then in the post-hook you delete the tables created before, not sure if this can work, not tested, but you do reduce the amount of tables written to the Database, which is the main drawback of the 1st approach although for a short period of time)